# Does imenu sopport sub-indexes?

Tags: imenu

I'm trying to add support for `imenu` in a major mode I currently writing.
Reading documentation I've found that its API looks simple and all I want to do is to write a function and bind it to `imenu-create-index-function`.

Documentation for `imenu--index-alist` also declares something called `nested sub-alist`:

> A nested sub-alist element looks like (INDEX-NAME . SUB-ALIST).
>   The function ‘imenu--subalist-p’ tests an element and returns t
>   if it is a sub-alist.

Does it mean that one could make `imenu` have nested structure like?

```
- index 1
  - sub-index
    - ...
- index 2
```

I've tried to return following from funciton bound to `imenu-create-index-function`:

```
'(("item 1" . '(("sub-item" . 1))) ("item 2" . 1))
```

And error says that it violates `integer-or-marker-p` at `'(("sub-item" . 1))`.

If nested structures are possible, how to form them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to represent structured menu with `imenu`.

A valid alist shape could be:

```
(list
 (list "Title 1"
       (list "Title 11"
             '("Index Name 1" . 1)
             '("Index Name 2" . 1)))
 (list "Title 2"
       '("Index Name 21" . 1)
       '("Index Name 22" . 1)))
```

The error was caused by quoting of `'(("sub-item" . 1))` form.

Comment: But how do you have the items that have both the marker and the nested items? In the example you provided you'd be able to jump to nested children but not "Title 1" itself